# How to replace array dictionary in json with dictionary with variables in linux

Tags: json, linux, jq

I have a need to batch replace an array structure in several json files.

I can replace the array in sample.json with plain text

```
# sample.json
{ 
  "persons": [ 
    { 
      "name": "test1", 
      "age": 20 
 
    }, 
    { 
      "name": "test2", 
      "age": 21 
    } 
  ] 
}
```

```
DATA='[{"name": "tony", "age": 22}]'   
jq --argjson newdata "$DATA" '.persons[0] = $newdata' sample.json > tmp && mv tmp sample.json
```

But when the text I replace **contains variables**, I get an error

```
NAME="namevar"
DATA="[{"name": "$NAME", "age": 22}]" 
jq --argjson newdata "$DATA" '.persons = $newdata' sample.json > tmp && mv tmp sample.json
```

The error is as follows and an empty *tmp* file is generated

```
jq: invalid JSON text passed to --argjson
Use jq --help for help with command-line options,
or see the jq manpage, or online docs  at https://stedolan.github.io/jq
```

How can I modify the replaced text to carry variables and replace them correctly? Looking forward to your reply.

That is, the expected result is

```
# sample.json after replace
{ 
  "persons": [ 
    { 
      "name": "namevar", 
      "age": 20 
    }
  ] 
}
```

Comment: Quick fix by properly escaping double quotes within double quotes: `DATA="[{\"name\": \"$NAME\", \"age\": 22}]"` (or keep single quotes for the static parts: `DATA='[{"name": "'"$NAME"'", "age": 22}]'`). However, you'd be safer by not injecting the (possibly poorly escaped) contents of `$NAME`. Rather introduce a programmatic approach to accept parameters with external values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `echo $DATA`, you'll see that the quotes are missing.

---

Use

```
DATA='[{"name": "'"$NAME"'", "age": 22}]'
```

To make sure the double quotes around the key are preserved, then your jq filter works just fine:

```
➜  /tmp jq . sample.json
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "name": "test1",
      "age": 20
    },
    {
      "name": "test2",
      "age": 21
    }
  ]
}
➜  /tmp
➜  /tmp NAME="namevar"
➜  /tmp DATA='[{"name": "'"$NAME"'", "age": 22}]'
➜  /tmp
➜  /tmp
➜  /tmp jq --argjson newdata "$DATA" '.persons = $newdata' sample.json
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "name": "namevar",
      "age": 22
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to build DATA with jq: `DATA=$(jq -cn --arg name "$NAME" --arg age 22 '[$ARGS.named]')`